# Sorting an Array of X and Y Vertice Points ? iOS / Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, vertices

I have a Core Data entity called Line. Each line contains an instance of a VerticePoint which contains an x and y property. These x and y vertices form simple 2D polygons.

What I want to do is sort an array of these Line objects which is in random order so that the origin of the shape, the bottom left point, is always the first element in the array, then followed by the remaining vertices wound in counter-clockwise direction from the origin.

So say the points in my original array are (x y axis is centred at 0,0) :

```
x = 20, y = 20
x = 20 , y= 10
x = 10, y=10
x = 10, y =20
x = 15, y = 10
```

I want to sort them like so :

```
x = 10, y=10
x = 15, y = 10
x = 20 , y= 10
x = 20, y = 20
x = 10, y =20
```

Many thanks

Comment: It's not really clear how you want to sort the vertices: "counter-clockwise around the origin" sounds like the vertices should be arranged roughly circularly around (0, 0), yet your example shows them ordered around their center (15, 15). You should more precisely describe how the sorting should work.

Comment: FROM the origin - not around. That's not what I wrote.

Comment: What does "FROM the origin mean"? Is there always a point on the origin? Or should we start with the point closest to the origin?

Comment: counter-clockwise around which point?

Comment: If you read carefully, I've said the origin is always the bottom left point.

Comment: Yes but then you say the origin is (0, 0) but there's not point at 0, 0.

Comment: Hey, and, I'm really trying to help to get your specification right and show you that it is not understandable for everyone.

Comment: Apologies - the axes are centred at 0,0, not the origin.

Comment: It might make sense if you express clearly how the points should be ordered.

Comment: The origin (bottom left of the shape) will always be the lowest x and lowest y value. I then want to proceed from this point to all points counter-clockwise.

Comment: There still might be no point exactly on the lowest x and lowest y coordinate.

Comment: Yes - there will always be a point in the array with the lowest x and y value - this is the start point.

Comment: So in the example above it is x=10, y=10

Comment: Which one is the origin/start point if the array is `[(5, 10), (10, 5), (20, 20)]`?

Comment: Good point - 5,10 in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

of NSArray.

You can use more then one descriptor. Just initialize two descriptors one with x, one with y property.

Comment: How would this work with Core Data objects ? My VerticePoint is a child entity of the Line object.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a proposal for a precise specification:

1. Assume a first quadrant coordinate system (with the y axis pointing up).
2. Find the center of the axis aligned bounding box of all points.
3. Sort the points by the angle of a vector from the center to the point. To calculate the angle consider a vector pointing south west to be at 0° with angles ascending in counter-clockwise direction.

And here's a solution:

```
NSArray *points = @[
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint){20, 20}],
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint){20, 10}],
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint){10, 10}],
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint){10, 20}],
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint){15, 10}],
];

CGPoint min = [points[0] CGPointValue];
CGPoint max = min;
for (NSValue *value in points) {
    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    min.x = fminf(point.x, min.x);
    min.y = fminf(point.y, min.y);
    max.x = fmaxf(point.x, max.x);
    max.y = fmaxf(point.y, max.y);
}

CGPoint center = {
    0.5f * (min.x + max.x),
    0.5f * (min.y + max.y),
};

NSLog(@"center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(center));

NSNumber *(^angleFromPoint)(id) = ^(NSValue *value){
    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    CGFloat theta = atan2f(point.y - center.y, point.x - center.x);
    CGFloat angle = fmodf(M_PI - M_PI_4 + theta, 2 * M_PI);
    return @(angle);
};

NSArray *sortedPoints = [points sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    return [angleFromPoint(a) compare:angleFromPoint(b)];
}];

NSLog(@"sorted points: %@", sortedPoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement method for your VerticePoint object which do the comparison, something like that:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(VerticePoint *)vpoint
{
    if (self.x > vpiont.x)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (self.x < vpiont.x)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if (self.y > vpiont.y)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (self.y < vpiont.y)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else 
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

And after that if you have your array with VerticePoint object you call:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Hope this help.

//EXTENDED

If you don't want to create subclass of NSManagedObject you can use NSSortDescriptor:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ENTITYNAME" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorX = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"yourObjecy.x" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorY = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"yourObjecy.y" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorX, sortDescriptorY, nil]];

NSArray *sortedResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

// EXTENDED

Or the easiest solution is

```
NSArray *returnedVertices = [verticesPassed sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    //Cast to your object:
    VerticePoint *p1 = (VerticePoint*)obj1;
    VerticePoint *p2 = (VerticePoint*)obj2;
    if (p1.x > p2.x)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (p1.x < p2.x)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if (p1.y > p2.y)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (p1.y < p2.y)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else 
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

];

Comment: What are self.x and self.y ?

Comment: I assume that your VerticePoint class contain property float x; and property float y;. You add this method to your class you want to sort, which is VerticePoint, right? And this is condition you want to use when sorting.

Comment: No - the array contains vertices point core data objects, but the code is not in this class.

Comment: You can create subclass of NSManagedObject for vertices point and add this method to it. And by calling sortedArrayUsingSelector: on your array containing vertices point it should work.

Comment: I am trying this, but am getting an error of unrecognised selector send to NSArrayI :  NSArray *sortDescriptorsX = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"origin.x" ascending:YES]];
    NSArray *sortDescriptorsY = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"origin.y" ascending:YES]];
    
    NSArray * finishedSort = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorsX, sortDescriptorsY, nil];
    
    NSArray *returnedVertices = [verticesPassed sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:finishedSort];
    
    return returnedVertices;

Comment: On which line do you have this error? Maybe your key: origin.x is wrong.

Comment: It works if I pass just one sort descriptor, but not both.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco I don't know why it's not working for you. I still think that my first solution is the best. I added one more solution in the previous post so fell free to try it.